# Alternative to fiberglass driveway markers

Tags: driveway

I am looking for method for making my own driveway markers. I do not like fiberglass orange markers as they always break, their color fades from sun light after a season or two. And they are bad for environment as they are hard to recycle or impossible to recycle.

Comment: Shopping questions ("where can I find" or "which should I buy") are considered offtopic here, I'm afraid.

Comment: I use 1/2" PVC electrical conduit (gray, sunlight-resistant) with reflective tape on top (orange, from the folks that make the best tapes in the USA, so it has not fallen off or degraded) and they have been working fine for more than a decade. No breakage, some have been bent, but can be unbent with application of heat. Costs considerably less than most driveway markers do, as well. You could rephrase and edit your question to be about alternatives, rather than "a shopping question" which is indeed off-topic. **Metal driveway markers** will find you what there are available in a search.

Comment: @Ecnerwal "the folks that make the best tapes in the USA" Just trying to get this straight, are these the same folks that make the best tape in Minnesota?

Comment: @GlenYates They even Mine and Manufacture in Minnesota, so I understand. Or used to, anyway. MMM.

Comment: This is no longer a shopping question, so the 2nd round of VtC as shopping should not be applicable. It's now "how to make"...

Answer (score 1):

So the problems:

1. fiberglass always break
2. their color fades from sun light after a season or two
3. hard to recycle

Solution:

1. Get clear glass bottles (think glass soda pop bottles or beer bottles; seems like a good excuse to buy a 6 pack)
2. Coat interior of bottle with a reflective UV resistant paint
3. Aluminum poles/tubing conduit sized to barely fit in bottle
4. Drive aluminum in ground deep enough to stay in place
5. Place bottles on to poles upside down

Glass and aluminum are quite durable to the elements, very recyclable, and the glass will protect the paint from the elements.

Comment: I'd be worried that a visitor or a delivery vehicle 
(I've seen both of those hit driveway markers many times) will run into one of the markers and break the glass, then you'll have broken glass on the driveway.

Comment: @MosheKatz A plastic bottle is better in many ways, but it isn't really recycled in the vast majority of places and UV discolors the plastic; at that point, going with fiberglass makes more sense to me. That concern can also be mitigated by simply moving it a little bit further away from the driveway.

Comment: The problem is that you want a *retroreflective* marker for this application, and what you described isn't it